# App crashing Android

Tags: java, android, crash

Anyone got any Idea why this code is not working, It was working fine until I tried to install the Google AdMob Ads SDK then all of a sudden the app crashes every time it I try and run it.

```
package co.miniz.RageToonViewer;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import co.miniz.RageToonViewer.R;
import co.miniz.RageToonViewer.ImageNumbers;
import co.miniz.RageToonViewer.NoRepeatRandom;
import co.miniz.RageToonViewer.Download;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RageToonViewerActivity extends Activity {
FileReader reader;
URL url;
Download DL;
NoRepeatRandom randGen;
ImageNumbers noOfImages;
ImageView imView;
Gallery g;
Text text1;
Bitmap bmImg;
TextView tv;
AssetManager assetManager;
int random;
int prevRand = -10;
int noOfFiles ;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        assetManager = getAssets();
        DL = new Download();
        imView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
        imView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        //----- Get Number OF Images -----
        noOfImages = new ImageNumbers();
        noOfFiles = noOfImages.GetNumber();

        //----- Set Button and Text outPut for testing -----
        Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv.setText("Click above for a random RageToon!");


        //----- Generate Random Number -----
        randGen = new NoRepeatRandom(0, noOfFiles);
        random = randGen.GetRandom();

        //----- Set First Image -----
        imView.setImageBitmap(GetImage());

        //----- Set up Button Click Action -----
        button1main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText("Click above for a random RageToon!" + noOfFiles);
                noOfFiles = noOfImages.GetNumber();
                imView.setImageBitmap(GetImage());
            }
         });

        imView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText("Click above for a random RageToon!" + noOfFiles);
                noOfFiles = noOfImages.GetNumber();
                imView.setImageBitmap(GetImage());
            }
        });
} 

public Bitmap GetImage() {

    random = randGen.GetRandom();
    URL tempURL = null;
    try {
        tempURL = new URL("http://miniz.co/RageToonApp/Images/" + random + ".jpg");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap TempImage = DL.getRemoteImage(tempURL, tv);

    if (TempImage == null)
    {
        TempImage = GetImage();
    }
   return TempImage;
}
}
```

When Debugging I can see an java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in the LogCat view.

Thanks for any Help ! 
Ross.

edit :  From LogCat

```
07-17 01:35:14.680: WARN/dalvikvm(3540): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40023160)
07-17 01:35:14.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{co.miniz.RageToonViewer/co.miniz.RageToon.RageToonViewerActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.miniz.RageToon.RageToonViewerActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@458a4278
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.miniz.RageToon.RageToonViewerActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@458a4278
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     ... 11 more
07-17 01:35:14.890: ERROR/SemcCheckin(3540): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
07-17 01:35:14.900: WARN/ActivityManager(1146): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.sonyericsson.android.jcrashcatcher.action.BUGREPORT_AUTO cmp=com.sonyericsson.android.jcrashcatcher/.JCrashCatcherService (has extras) }: not found
07-17 01:35:15.000: INFO/Process(1146): Sending signal. PID: 3540 SIG: 3
07-17 01:35:15.000: INFO/dalvikvm(3540): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-17 01:35:15.000: ERROR/dalvikvm(3540): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
07-17 01:35:15.060: ERROR/SemcCheckin(1681): Get Crash Level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
07-17 01:35:15.170: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2189): GC freed 264 objects / 16000 bytes in 32ms
07-17 01:35:19.036: WARN/jdwp(3540): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
```

Edit: Thanks for the reply but the code is still not working after fixing the path names and such. 
I have found out that every app I now create in eclipse that uses any for of connection to the internet will now crash when I try and run it on my phone ?
They also crash when I use the code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

I hope this will help in determining what has gone wrong.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace from your logcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From exception it is clear that dalvik is looking your file "RageToonViewerActivity" under path **"co.miniz.RageToon.RageToonViewerActivity"** but is defined in package **"package co.miniz.RageToonViewer"** hence not able to locate.

1. I would advice you to go to android manifest file and where you activity is defined,give full path.

   ```
   <activity android:name="co.miniz.RageToonViewer.RageToonViewerActivity" // change this line
       android:screenOrientation="portrait">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```

2.Clean your Project. and have a go!!

Gud luck!!

Answer (score 0):

mind this description: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.miniz.RageToon.RageToonViewerActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader`

check your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used: `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Now I used the code below and get no crashes.

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```